# tf.device() appeared exception

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

When I use tf.device() to assign GPU number, it appeared an exception. It's my first time to ask question in Stack Overflow, if it has some error, please forgive me, and tell me.

When I put allow_soft_placement=True in code, it works.

Comment: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation save/SaveV2: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'

Comment: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation save/SaveV2: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Registered kernels:

Comment: InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation save/SaveV2: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Registered kernels:

Comment: The error messages from your comments and the code in your "answer" should all go in your question. You can edit the question to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def init_graph(self):
    """
    init bert graph
    """
    with self.tf_instance.device('device:GPU:{}'.format(str(self.gpu_no))):
        # add tokenizer
        from bert import tokenization
        self.tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(self.args.vocab_file)
        from bert import modeling
        bert_config = modeling.BertConfig.from_json_file(self.args.config_file)
        self.model = modeling.BertModel(config=bert_config,
                                        is_training=False,
                                        input_ids=self.input_ids,
                                        input_mask=self.input_mask,
                                        token_type_ids=self.input_type_ids,
                                        use_one_hot_embeddings=False)

        # get output weights and output bias
        reader = self.tf_instance.train.NewCheckpointReader(self.args.ckpt_file)
        output_weights = reader.get_tensor('output_weights')
        output_bias = reader.get_tensor('output_bias')

        # get result op
        output_layer = self.model.get_pooled_output()
        logits = self.tf_instance.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
        logits = self.tf_instance.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
        self.probabilities = self.tf_instance.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1)

        sess_config = self.tf_instance.ConfigProto()
        sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

        graph = self.probabilities.graph
        saver = self.tf_instance.train.Saver()
        self.sess = self.tf_instance.Session(config=sess_config, graph=graph)
        self.sess.run(self.tf_instance.global_variables_initializer())
        self.tf_instance.reset_default_graph()
        saver.restore(self.sess, self.args.ckpt_file)
```